# Return type of a web method changed from list to array

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

This might sound like a question from stone age. I was hoping I could get some help here
I've gone a little rusty in ASP.NET and thought I would do some refreshers.

So I sat down and wrote a small asmx service. In one of the web methods, i coded it to return a list of a type. (List < Type >).
When I added a web reference , the return type of the same method changed to < Type > [ ].

I was wondering why it changed and what i could do preserve the return type

Answer (score 2):

If you already have Service Reference added Right click your ServiceReference to open ServiceReference Configuration window. Change the Collection Return Type to System.List.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The webservice server and client communicate via SOAP. In SOAP, there is no difference between a list and an array.

Since the client only sees the SOAP interface, it has no way of knowing whether the server used a list or an array. The .NET "add service reference" dialog defaults to arrays, but you can specify an alternative when clicking on "Advanced":

[image: screenshot]